# How would the Golden Gate Bridge collapse without maintenance?

Tags: science-based, infrastructure

All maintenance and repairs stop for ever on the Golden Gate Bridge.  It doesn't get much traffic either— only about 20 cars a day.  Assuming there are no major natural (or unnatural) disasters, how long would it take before the bridge becomes impassible?  Would the bridge ever completely collapse?

Comment: Do you really need [tag:hard-science] here as opposed to [tag:science-based]?

Comment: I don't think there is any paper reliably answering what would fail first.

Comment: I changed the tag— thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There is a list of ongoing and yearly repairs here: http://goldengatebridge.org/research/caretakers.php

Comment: According to the book "The World Without Us" by Alan Weisman, suspension and truss bridges would collapse after two or three centuries without maintenance. The cause would be rust eventually filling the expansion joints, causing damage during hot weather.